# How to keep return type of a function Promise<MyObject[]> while calling forEach?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function `search` that currently returns `Promise<MyObject[]>`:

```
export function search(args: SearchInput) {
        return SomeInterface.performSearch(args)
            .then(xmlRequest => AnotherInterface.post(xmlRequest))
            .then(xmlResponse => SomeInterface.performSearchResponse(xmlResponse)) // performSearchResponse returns Promise<MyObject[]>
            .then(searchResponse => searchResponse.forEach(convertIDs)); // returns Promise<void>
    }

function convertIDs(obj: MyObject) {
    if (obj.id === 'foo') {
        obj.id = 'bar';
    }
    return obj;
}
```

I am trying to add a new line at the end that applies `convertIDs` to the results of the function. But in doing this the function no longer returns `Promise<MyObject[]>` but instead `Promise<void>`. This in turn breaks the code further down the line that expects the results of this function to be type `Promise<MyObject[]>`.

Is there a way to apply this `convertIDs` function to the results while also maintaining the original return type?

Comment: _Don't_ use `.forEach`? As the compiler is telling you, that doesn't return anything. This isn't a TypeScript problem; the _implementation_ is wrong and the error is trying to help you. Maybe you want `.map`, which returns the array? But without a [mre] it's hard to say.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: You posted a sample consider posting what does NOT work perhaps including how this is called.

Comment: @mikemaccana no, the `forEach` callback is not asynchronous here

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the Comma Operator to get the original value back

```
 .then(searchResponse =>
          ( searchResponse.forEach(convertIDs) , searchResponse )
       ); // returns the same Promise<MyObject[]> it got
```

(comma operator voids all the values except the last one which it returns)

---

That's the same as

```
 .then(searchResponse => {
    searchResponse.forEach(convertIDs) 
    return searchResponse 
  })
```

Comment: so would the return value still have the convertIDs function applied?

Comment: @Barry assuming your convertIDs retorns `void` and edits the object itself, yes. Alsoo see updated.

Comment: added the convertIDs code. it returns type MyObject and does edit the object itself